# MSTest with Ninject, MVC3 and WCF

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, mstest

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 project that calls a WCF service to get data. The WCF service in turn uses managers and repositories etc. (in other class library projects) to get the required data.

I have applied Ninject on both the web project and the WCF project. Because I used Nuget to install Ninject MVC3, it has created a class in APP_START with bootstrapper, webactivator etc.

Now I want to write unit tests using Microsoft's testing framework, and not NUnit etc.

How do I get started? That is, what do I write in the unit test classes to use Ninject to provide mock implementations of interfaces to the web and wcf projects?

The examples I have seen, use Moq extension, which seems complex at first sight. I'd rather go without Moq if possible.

I would appreciate any links, examples, related responses, etc. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use Ninject to create instances of the classes you want to test. Just create an instance of the controller or service you want to test and pass a mock object as constructor parameter for each dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this now. I'll wait for any other suggestions before marking this as an answer.

Comment: OK, so I'm on board with this now. Planning to use Moq as well as it only helps in creating runtime mock class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @Remo Gloor says, you should definitely not be using a DI container in your tests.

You may find [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com) to be useful in this space. It has some automocking container capabilities (and you should also have a search about for that term). Remember that there's nothing simple about having lots of implicit mocking and wtuff being magically wired up in tests - the less you rely on magic and big object graphs in your tests the better.